# ARM cross-compiler Linux System install error unable to locate package

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, debian, cross-compiling

I am using a Debian Linux host computer. I would like to cross-compile some ARM Mali OpenCL sample code from the SDK. I have been searching all over the Internet and I have found several websites that state that I should run either one of these install commands:

sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf

However, when I run these commands, I get an error message stating "Unable to locate package".

Additional information, I ran these commands before the "install gcc and g++ commands":

sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update

I noticed an errors:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/linaro-maintainers/toolchain/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

Any advice or help?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

I assuming you are running Debian wheezy based on the error message.

I would recommend upgrading to Debian 8 jessie and follow the installation instructions at the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains#In_jessie_.28Debian_8.29).
I also suggests that you remove the dead ppa url in your apt sources before upgrading.

If upgrading is not an option, you might be able to find the
binaries for your architecture or install them manually.

Note: In Debian 9 stretch, which is currently in testing, this should no longer be an issue.